# Append the global function in active accordion panel

Tags: jquery-ui

```
$("#accordion").accordion({
    icons: icons,
    collapsible: true,
    heightStyle: "content",
    active: false,
    header: "> div > h3",
    activate: function (event, ui) {
        setTimeout(function(){
    item(ui);
        },100);
    }
    }).sortable({
    axis: "y",
    handle: "h3",
    stop: function (event, ui) {
        ui.item.children("h3").triggerHandler("focusout");
        $(this).accordion("refresh");
    }
});
function item(ui){
var active = $('#accordion').accordion( "option", "active" );
var activeid = $('.ui-accordion-header-active').attr('id');
  ithtml = '';   
    $.post('sample.php',function(data){
   $.each(data, function( index, value){
var dividit = value.ItemID;
var cls = (value.IsVeg==0) ? 'green' : 'red';
var bord = (value.IsVeg==0) ? 'green_border' : 'red_border';
ithtml += 'some html content';
    $(ui.newPanel).find(".normal_add__box").remove().end().append(ithtml);
},'json');   
}

$('#dialog').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    buttons: [{
    text: "Submit",
    type:"submit",
    id:"Btn"
 }]
});
```

I want to know where to append the function item(ui) to active panel when i clicked a button(where the button is in dialog with id **Btn**) what i mean is the dialog will open when class .normal_add_box is clicked and when i click submit the function item(ui) must be used and append data to active accordion panel from where the dialog is opened.